# Ubuntu One: can you shutdown your computer when syncing is in process?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, shutdown, sync, reboot

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 on my other laptop. I logged into my ubuntu one account and it starts syncing files that I stored from my other laptop. However the files are too big and the syncing process takes too long. If I shut my laptop down, will the syncing process aborts completely or will it resume the next time I log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will resume when the computer is turned on. I have done this before. When the computer is back on and you are logged in, the Ubuntu One application will see that some of the files have not been synced.